# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name

Tags: core-data, tabbar, nsmanagedobjectcontext, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I have a window based applicaiton with tab bar and navigation bar integrated into it. On the navigation bar have a custom button which opens a table view.

On clicking on the cell of the table I want to open a new table view controller. But as soon as I click on the cell of first table I get an exception that

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'AddForm''
```

I have checked that `AddForm` is in right place.

I have tried all the solutions given above and on other thread, but still stuck. I hope someone can help me.

The flow is something like this

ListButton (on click opens a list view) -> a table view opens -> (on click of a cell should open a new table view Controller and fetch data from core data)

My root view controller code is in the second table view controller file... is that what I am doing wrong? I am doing so because I don't need the core data before that....

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I Used to have the same problem first of all check in your AppDelegate.m class if the managedObjectContext is created

if it is created check if it is pass it as argument
something like this

```
 MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

if that is correct for you main view just be sure that you are passing it  through your views something like this

```
self.detailViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

well at least that works for me =)

Comment: I had the exact same error and it was because I was trying to get fetch an entity from an object managed context that hadn't been set up yet. Make sure to set the managed object context property of whatever view controller you are creating.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this problem is misspelling the name of the entity or getting the capitalization wrong. Check that `AddForm` is spelled exactly the same in the code and the data model editor.