# NSInternalInconsistencyException could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to set up coredata in a project I have already started.. I have gone though some other errors, but have now narrowed it down to this,

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not
>   locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Manuf''

I think I have narrowed down the problem and a possible solution to this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252828/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-entityforname-could-not-locate-an) re: Alex's answer.

However I am not totally sure this is the case for me, as the reason for my confusion is that instead of setting everything up in my app-delegate & viewcontrollers I am actually using my app-delegate & a object class. So I am hoping someone can help me isolate and fix my issue here...

This is the segment of code in my object class thats giving me the issue. It is almost identical to the template code produced by xcode for coredata apps, however its excluding the sorting and tableview stuff because I dont need that.. I am just dumping a bunch of NSData into my coredata object.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Manuf" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; //this is the line where my code fails and generates the error in the log
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

UPDATE:

This is where I think I am going wrong. In the template code the controller and the context is set up inside the appdelegate like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    ICDMasterViewController *controller = (ICDMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

and because I am doing all my stuff in a object class I am not sure how to initialize this in my app delegate?

As opposed to what I am trying to do now in my appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    //Add status bar
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController; //Adds RootViewController to the NavigationController interface
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //try setting up context for my nsobjectclass EngineResponses
    EngineResponses *engineResponses = [[EngineResponses alloc] init];
    engineResponses.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Morning.

There's three things I'd check :

1) Is `self.managedObjectContext` `nil`? (what do you get if you `NSLog(@"%@", self.managedObjectContext);`?

2) Does your model description contain an entity called `Manuf` - it's probably case sensitive :)

3) When you create your coordinator, are you correctly loading in the model from (2) ?

Comment: 1, Yes it is nil. 2, Yes most defiantly checked this several times made sure spelling an case matches. 3, I am not sure.. this is where I think I am going wrong.. in the template xocde prog, the app-delegate sets up the controller and the context in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I have left this out atm.. because I don't know how to initialize it for a object instead of a class... do you have any idea? I have updated my question above with what I am missing (which is what i think is causing this issue.) thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: (1) yes it's nil - well it _shouldn't_ be! The reason you're getting the exception is because you're not telling it which context to look for `Manuf` in! You need to have created your managed object context before you try to use it ;)

Comment: yea, thats what I am trying to create now.. but I am not sure how to create it.. from what I can tell in the template code generated by excode its declared in the appdelegate under didFinishLanuchingWithOptions right?

Comment: No idea - add it to your question and I might be able to help ;)

Comment: yup, added my app delegate method where I am trying to set up the context and also added the coredata xcode templates version..

Comment: The interesting bit is the `managedObjectContext` method your app delegate - that's the method that will create your context. I would look at what you have got to see why you aren't getting one :) PS The way you pass the context into your controller looks fine.

Comment: okay, thanks for the reply.. well I'm abit baffled as the managedObjectContext method is identical to the one from the template code... so I'm not quite sure where I am going wrong... I have been working on this for a couple of days already.. starting to really get me down.. lol :( Thanks for the help however.

Comment: actually I would say one of the problems with me the face that I am passing the context to the wrong instance of my nsobject class...

Comment: Oh, I guess that would cause this problem too ;)